# how do i make js dectect whats typed in a input box

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make js detect whats in a input box, and if the user typed in a code, something will happen so far I got this

```js
function input() {
    document.getElementById('hehe').value
    if (value == "hello") {
        window.alert("SOMETHING");
    } else {
        window.alert("SOMETHING");
    }
}
```

```html
<input id="hehe" type="text" oninput="input()">
```

but it's not working for some reason and I can't see why

Comment: You don't assign the result of `value` to a variable. Is this a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to save the value before you can use it. `document.getElementById('hehe').value` RETURNS the value of the input textfield but in the next line you're using the non existing variable `value`.

just change it to:

```
function input() {
    var value = document.getElementById('hehe').value
    if (value == "hello") {
        window.alert("SOMETHING");
    } else {
        window.alert("SOMETHING");
    }
}
```

or use it directly:

```
function input() {
    if (document.getElementById('hehe').value == "hello") {
        window.alert("SOMETHING");
    } else {
        window.alert("SOMETHING");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning the DOM element value to a variable. You should write:

```
var value = document.getElementById('hehe').value;
```

Or, using jQuery:

```
var value = $('#hehe').val();
```

However, another automated way to detect entered text, using [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com) library, is `data-bind`. It automatically synchronizes the DOM element with your `Model` after applying the binding to your `ModelView`.

Here is an example: ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SamiAlmalki/q919ncot/))

HTML:

```
<p>Name: <input data-bind="textInput: name"></p>
<h1>The typed name is: <span data-bind="text: name"></span>.</h1>
```

JavaScript:

```
ko.applyBindings({
    name: ko.observable("SOMETHING")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `onkeypress` instead of `oninput`.

http://jsfiddle.net/VDd6C/8/